# What is meant by input/ output purity?

Tags: oop, functional-programming

So I am new to functional programming and a bit of a novice with OOP. I've never heard of something being pure or to be specific what input/ output purity is in functional programming. I heard that you cannot have this in OOP but I really can't find anything useful around. I just need a simple "oh, that's basically where the input is lacking blah blah and the code is able to blah blah because of it".

Comment: You're probably looking for [*this*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)

Comment: I was looking for something dumbed down to the max. Wikipedia pages tend to throw you in the deep end almost.

Comment: Essentially, it means your code doe not produce side-effects and functions have referential transparency, i.e. the function always evaluates to the same result in any context. There are languages that try to reconcile OOP with functional programing, Scala being the prime example. OOP is sort of built around mutability, but it doesn't *have* to be mutable.

Comment: That makes sense but why wouldn't a functional programming language cause side effects? Surely any language in OOP or FP can cause side effects?

Comment: @WhatsThat it *can* have side-effects, but functional programming doesn't encourage it. In fact, it encourages exactly the opposite: immutable objects and pure functions.

Comment: Pure languages don't directly execute effects but return descriptions of them for execution by the runtime system. This allows the effects produced by a function to be captured in the return type. I don't think there's any reason you couldn't create a pure OO language however and impure FP languages exist. So the distinction is pure vs impure rather than OO vs FP.

Comment: BTW, don't avoid reading docs bc it looks "deep". I bet you that if you bothered reading the two bullet points in the beginning of wiki - you'd get the gist of it.

Comment: @WhatsThat A pure functional language (e.g. Haskell) cannot have side-effects. If you are using side-effects, you are no longer using FP.

Comment: String class in Java is pure. A method on a String that returns a String will never mutate itself but rather make a new String object. It's functional and OO.